# Java : sort array

Tags: java, arraylist

I have list of objects.
Object = Invoice_id,client_name

My list looks like that :

> 1,tom
>   1,tom
>   1,tom
>   2,tim
>   2,tim
>   3,rob
>   3,rob
>   4,mike
>   4,mike

I would like to obain that :

> 1,tom
>   2,tim
>   3,rob
>   4,mike

I have tried that :

```
for (Invoice invoice : invoices){
  mapOfInvoicesId.put(invoice.getId(), invoice.getId());
}
mapOfInvoicesId.keySet()
```

But the ids are not in the same order as in the initial list.
I don't know why.  I want to keep the same order.

If anyone knows why...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement *equals* and *hashCode* in your data object class.
2. Use *LinkedHashSet* (to keep order as you add items) to keep only distinct ones.
3. Add all items to the set.
4. Iterate over the set and print all items.

Profit!